# Mysql 5.7 json column WHERE IN not working as expected

Tags: mysql, json

This sql returns correct result:

```
select * from `user` where `profile`->"$.year" IN ("2001")
```

But when I add more than one values

```
select * from `user` where `profile`->"$.year" IN ("2001", "1")
```

returns empty

It seems "In" statement not working as expected on JSON column in Mysql 5.7?

Comment: [mcve], please.

Comment: Use `JSON_UNQUOTE()` or the `->>` operator to unquote the JSON scalar value. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-modification-functions.html#function_json-unquote

Answer (score 0):

See documentation:

> [11.6 The JSON Data Type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html)
>
> ...
>
> - [Comparison and Ordering of JSON Values](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-comparison)
>
> ...
>
> The following comparison operators and functions are not yet
>   supported with JSON values:
>
> - [BETWEEN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between)
> - [IN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in)
> - [GREATEST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_greatest)
> - [LEAST()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_least)
>
> A workaround for the comparison operators and functions just listed is
>   to cast JSON values to a native MySQL numeric or string data type so
>   they have a consistent non-JSON scalar type.
>
> ...

Try:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM `user`
WHERE CAST(`profile` -> "$.year"  AS UNSIGNED) IN ("2001", "1");
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a5d5116ffe75f42c7b8748a37e7412c6).

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
select * from `user` where json_unquote(JSON_EXTRACT(profile,'$.year')) in ('2001', '1')
```

or like this:

```
select * from `user` whereJSON_EXTRACT(profile,'$.year') in ('"2001"', '"1"')
```

cause mysql seems like parsing json data to string,it works in my console